# How to filter OData collection where attribute does not exist?

Tags: rest, api, odata

I have an OData collection where the data looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:5488/odata/$metadata#folders",
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "samples",
            "_id": "79a91bc9-9083-4442-ac8d-ad30777ac8c8",
            "creationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.670Z",
            "modificationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.670Z",
            "shortid": "18xQnNv"
        },
        {
            "name": "Population",
            "folder": {
                "shortid": "18xQnNv"
            },
            "_id": "7406269b-669c-41ce-92f3-f540792df07e",
            "creationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.750Z",
            "modificationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.750Z",
            "shortid": "0ppeLV"
        },
        {
            "name": "Invoice",
            "folder": {
                "shortid": "18xQnNv"
            },
            "_id": "525aff6a-6b10-4ad6-93ce-e9c753e8ade0",
            "creationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.790Z",
            "modificationDate": "2019-08-05T04:39:00.790Z",
            "shortid": "G3i2B3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Default",
            "_id": "58daf5aa-1f13-4ff9-be1f-8cb11a812485",
            "creationDate": "2019-08-07T22:56:45.160Z",
            "modificationDate": "2019-08-07T22:56:45.160Z",
            "shortid": "Sm8LpmP"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to exclude the objects which have the attribute "folder". I've tried using a GET request: `http://localhost:5488/odata/folders?$filter=folder eq null` with no luck. Is this even possible and is there a way to filter my request like this?

Comment: In the current version of ODataLib at the time of the post, your query should have worked for an OData V4 compliant implementation given the JSON that is posted. Next time please include the relative snippet from the $metadata or Edm document, that will define the schema for us in a way that we can provide a definitive response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might be able to use [the **all** lambda operator](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/csprd05/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.01-csprd05-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_LambdaOperators) to accomplish this.  The operator all will always return true on empty collections.  So if you make a condition that no folder attribute that actually exists will ever evaluate to true on, then the result ***should*** be a filter of only those objects that have an empty attribute.

This is just a theory.  You'll need to test, but it would maybe look something like this on your sample.

```
http://localhost:5488/odata/folders?$filter=folder/all(f:f/shortid eq 'xxxxxx')
```

You didn't mention the version of OData your working with but lambda expressions are at least V4 and later.  Possibly earlier, not sure.

Comment: The OData service I'm using belongs to a report server (JSReport) I'm playing around with so I'm not entirely sure what version of OData they implemented on their API. It seems like http://localhost:5488/odata/folders?$filter=folder/all(f:f/shortid eq 'xxxxxx') isn't working for me. I still get the full collection unfiltered.

Comment: This query worked on another OData API that had a similar data structure. The API I tested it on had limited supported on lambda queries.

Comment: the _all_ lambda shouldn't work for OP because the `folder` property is singular and _not_ a collection.