# How to filter in OData for a specific value inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, odata

In our Cosmos database, we have an attribute for a document that is an array of objects. The objects in this array have two attributes, `Key` and `Value`. So it's "a bit like" a `IDictionary<string, string>`.

Here is some example data:

```
{
  // other attributes
  // .....
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "client",
      "Value": "Evil Corporation"
    },
    {
      "Key": "level1",
      "Value": "EUROPE"
    },
    {
      "Key": "level2",
      "Value": "UNITED KINGDOM"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, there are also objects in the database where `level2`, for example, does not exist, resulting in JSON like this:

```
{
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "client",
      "Value": "Evil Corporation"
    },
    {
      "Key": "level1",
      "Value": "EUROPE"
    }
  ]
}
```

A user is able to select `level2` filters through the UI so the application makes sure they are included. The user can also select filters and mark them as `excluded`, i.e. that he wants every result where a specific country is not present.

At first I created the following query in order to get all for a specific country:

```
&$filter=Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'client' and c/Value eq 'Evil Corporation') and (Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value eq 'UNITED KINGDOM')
```

I am having trouble with the query where I select every item where a specific country does not exist. I tried:

```
&$filter=Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'client' and c/Value eq 'Nestlé') and (Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value ne 'UNITED KINGDOM')
```

This now returns every item where `level2` is not `UNITED KINGDOM`, however if a document does not have `level2` configured at all, such as when there is no object with `key=level2` in the document, then it's not returned.

So, basically, I need this query:

```
(Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value ne 'UNITED KINGDOM')` and combine it somehow with `OR Tags/Any (c:c/Key {IS NOT PRESENT}
```

and this is where I am stuck.

I don't know how to write this into ODATA. When I searched Google for a non-existent column and ODATA it only returns results for people having issues with ODATA not returning a specific column, but that's exactly what I want to do.

I tried to write this query:

```
and (Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value ne 'UNITED KINGDOM') or Tags/All (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value ne 'UNITED KINGDOM'))
```

which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57405406/2823419

but it returns an error that it can't parse the query.

What function do I need to use?

Comment: Why are you doing this by hand instead of using eg EF Core's Cosmos provider? OData isn't SQL, nor a remote database access API. Some queries are impossible with OData while others are too hard to write

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Because I told my Product Owners that a specific feature they want will take some more time and extra effort because it's more complex than they think and then when I went on vacation they just implemented with outsourced colleagues in a hacky way. And surprise surprise, this hacky way now leads to a bug on production. And refactoring the whole feature will take too long and I need to quick fix this. Alternatively, I can omit this query and filter in the frontend, but I wanted to try to solve it through ODATA first. Is this not possible?

Comment: On the other hand, the document schema isn't optimal. A JSON object is already a dictionary, there's no need to have `Key` and `Value` tags. It looks like you tried to replicate an Entity-Attribute-Value schema in a document database, which simply doesn't need it. The whole point of a document DB like Cosmos is that you can write `{ 'client' : 'Evil Corporation', 'level1' : 'Europe'}`. Those levels are weird too. Nothing prevents you from nesting objects in JSON

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is true, I also don't like how these tags are stored in our application, but this is also sth. that cannot be changed quickly now. Gladly this is a microservice and in our other microservices we have a different structure for these "tags", but this is what we are given at the moment.

Comment: Then your query can't be written quickly either. The schema is *very* wrong, so writing any kind of query for this will be very difficult. You're trying to use OData, an API level protocol that works on **entities**, to reconstitute those entities from attribute/value pairs. That's the job of the controller or query resolver *behind* an OData API.

Comment: Was this data migrated from a relational database using the EAV *anti*pattern to emulate document storage? That was a bad design from the start, and completely inappropriate now. You have a document database now, there's no restriction on how many attributes an object can have. As for a *hierarchy* of objects, which here is represented by `level1` etc, you can simply nest the objects

Comment: `Because I told my Product Owners that a specific feature they want will take some more time and extra effort because it's more complex than they think and then` no, it's because the data is wrong and what they ask *will cost them enormously in Cosmos bills*. This schema takes a lot more space and the overly complex queries it needs will eat up a lot of CPU. All of those will be charged against the product owner's budget. Is the PO ready to admit responsibility for the huge bill? Will *they* request the budget for more RUs to process the same traffic?

Comment: I have no knowledge why this data is written in this way or if it was in a different way before then. It was done by a freelancer which I was hired to supersede. According to my boss he wanted to try out cosmos db and went for it. However, I dont think the problem lies with the database system but more with the structure of the data.

Comment: Yeah, nesting also doesn't work in this case, when you select multiple countries you also have, right now, multiple `level2` filters in the document. It can be heavily improved.

Comment: So we have a small dataset only at the moment, so it shouldnt be too expensive at the moment. The API call returns like 20 items at max at the moment. I would maybe then add the filtering in the frontend as a quick fix and then refactor the schema and the implementation for the long run, so we can use it on production and implement it correctly while production works.

Comment: Instead of `heavily improved` say `the bill can be heavily reduced`. On the cloud, mistakes have a direct impact on the monthly bill and Cosmos is *not* cheap. That's far easier to explain to POs. `we can use it on production and implement it correctly while production works.` unfortunately, this will take longer than simply using the correct design. Querying an EAV table is really hard on a database using SQL and JOINs. In this case you're trying to perform that JOIN with OData. How much will *your* wasted time cost?

Comment: In any case, even just for experimentation, try using the EF Core provider, make the query you want and inspect the HTTP call it sends to Cosmos using eg Fiddler. I think EF Core 6 can also log the HTTP query itself. A `not exists` like that will be very difficult to pull off though. Every query will be as hard to write as this one

Comment: First of all, thanks for the extensive answers! I might have miscommunicated a bit, but solving it in the frontend should be fairly easy. We would send the ODATA query without the `level2` filters, so it's always getting for all countries. And then based on the filter selection in the frontend, we would filter the API response. Of course this leads to more data in the response and more response time etc. but this fix would be implemented in 2 hours. Then, while production works as expected, we can fix the design which will take 1 sprint.

Comment: We havent used EF Core in this project, because it has (had) some limitations with Cosmos DB that we required. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/ef/core/providers/cosmos/limitations 

However, I can see that this list has been reduced, so we might be able to reevaluate this.

Comment: But still, the problem is, that this special `except this filter` is hacked in the frontend right now. THe backend does'nt even know that this functionality exists, because of the hacky way it was implemented. So we would need to open up some things there.

Comment: You forgot the network bandwidth bill. That's the greatest cost in all cloud bills. The cost of fixing code in production is a *lot* greater too.

Comment: You are absoloutely right that we should fix it correctly. I agree with you. But right now, production cannot be used, because on production this `level2` does not exist in any document. So we MUST implement a quick fix for this. We def. need to fix this correctly immedieatley, but we also need to make sure that production works today as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation, the OData specification has a *Logical Negation* operator: `not()`, it's usage is not explicitly documented in the spec but it is listed in [5.1.1.14 Operator Precedence](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html?#_Toc371341816)

The usage of this would be to wrap the expression that you want to *negate* inside a `not()` function:

`&$filter=Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'client' and c/Value eq 'Nestlé') and not((Tags/Any (c:c/Key eq 'level2' and c/Value eq 'UNITED KINGDOM'))`

or if you simply wanted to exclude all records if *any* key had a value of `'UNITED KINGDOM'` then you could more simply use this:

`&$filter=not(Tags/Any (t:t/Value eq 'UNITED KINGDOM'))`

---

**NOTE:**
`not(any())` should produce the same results as `all(field ne value)` but an `all()` lambda requires evaluation of every single record, whereas `any()` we break out of evaluation at the first match. `not(any())` should always produce the most efficient result, it is also more resilient to missing properties.